# Issue with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, on a null object reference when delete data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

The display from the Firebase database works fine, but when I try to delete an item from the database, the application crashes, although the deletion occurs. Writes on a null object reference in the string:

```
String postDescription = dataSnapshot.child("desc").getValue().toString();
```

Here is my code:

```
public class PostFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerPost;

private DatabaseReference postReference;

private View view;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

public PostFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false);

    recyclerPost = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_post);

    postReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
    postReference.keepSynced(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerPost.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerPost.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Query query = postReference.orderByChild("timestamp");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>()
                    .setQuery(query, Posts.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Posts model) {

            final String postId = getRef(position).getKey();
            postReference.child(postId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String postDescription = dataSnapshot.child("desc").getValue().toString();
                    holder.postDesc.setText(postDescription);                   
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            holder.delBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    postReference.child(postId).removeValue();
                }
            });


        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new PostViewHolder(view);
        }

    };

    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerPost.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView postDesc;
    private Button delBtn;
    private View view;

    public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
        postDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_description); 
        delBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.del_post_btn);

    }
}
}
```

Please tell me the solution to this problem.

Comment: If the application crashes, your logcat should contain an error message and stack trace. Please look those up, and ad them to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
            postReference.child(postId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String postDescription = dataSnapshot.child("desc").getValue().toString();
                holder.postDesc.setText(postDescription);                   
            }
          }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

You can use the method `exists()`:

> `public boolean exists ()`
>
> Returns true if the snapshot contains a non-null value.

It will check if the datasnapshot is in the
database, if it is not in the database then you can add a snackbar or a toast.

More information here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#exists()

Answer (score 0):

Every time a post is added to the adapter/list view, you now create a listener with `addValueEventListener` in your `onBindViewHolder`. This listener gets the value from the database, and then **keeps listening for changes** until you remove it. Since you never remove these listeners, over time they add up and things likely get out of sync.

The simplest solution is to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`:

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Posts model) {

    final String postId = getRef(position).getKey();
    postReference.child(postId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String postDescription = dataSnapshot.child("desc").getValue().toString();
            holder.postDesc.setText(postDescription);                   
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
        }
    });
```

When you use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, the listener is removed right after `onDataChange` fires for the first time.